# Using Reed Solomon decoding, do we need to know which shards are correct?

Tags: error-correction, reed-solomon

I am using Reed-Solomon error correction in a Java project. The library I use is JavaReedSolomon (https://github.com/Backblaze/JavaReedSolomon). There is an example of decoding using JavaReedSolomon:

```
byte[][] shards = new byte[NUM_SHARDS][SHARD_SIZE];
//shards is the array containing all the shards
ReedSolomon reedSolomon = ReedSolomon.create(NUM_DATA_SHARDS, NUM_PARITY_SHARDS);
reedSolomon.decodeMissing(shards, shardPresent, 0, shardSize);
```

The array shardPresent represents which shards are sure to be correct, for example, if you are sure that the 4th shard is correct, then shardPresent[3] equals true.

My question is, does Reed-Solomon decoding necessarily need to know which shards are correct or it is just how this library implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: the decoding procedure can recover from both unknown and known errors (erasures). A Reed-Solomon code (in fact, any [MDS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound#MDS_codes)) can correct twice as many erasures as errors. There are [multiple ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#Error_correction_algorithms) to determine the error locator.

It is likely the API in the library corresponds to its use case, i.e. there is probably some side-channel information about which parts of the data are correct.